# Importing Excel column as number using Blue prism

Tags: automation, blueprism

How do I make sure Blue Prism import the excel data as number, because currently it is picking everything as text.

Answer (score 2):

There is vbo in excel vbo for copying excel to data set. You can use excel vbo, it will copy in same format as of excel.

Answer (score 2):

After you have imported the Excel data as text into a data item or collection, then use a Calculation stage and under the Functions list expand Conversion and select ToNumber. Drop in the data item / collection with the data as text in it and click Paste. The output of this calculation should be what you are looking for.